# Viewing normals in Blender?

Tags: normals

I'm sure there is a way to view the normals, but I can't find it anywhere. Can you please tell me where to find this option?
Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

## 2.8

*Edit Mode* > *Viewport Overlays* > *Normals*.

In 2.8, the normals display settings are in the *Viewport Overlays* menu found in the top right of the 3D view by default, under *Normals*. Note that you must be in *Edit Mode*:

[image]

Comment: I'd like to see an update to this answer that applies to Blender 4.0

Answer (score 12):

In the 3D-View, while your Mesh object is in Editmode, open the properties area with <kbd>N</kbd> or the little plus sign on the upper right.

Find the panel called "Mesh Display". It has all you need.

[image: Mesh Display Panel]

Comment: It has "Show Weights", but not normals (the little perpendicular lines). Am I still missing something?

Comment: @pixelfoot, the button is right below "show weights". Click the third button under "Normals".

Comment: If the answer solves the problem, please consider marking it as solved