# How can I get rid of these weird shadows?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]
I was trying to find a solution on youtube but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Check if all your normals are pointing outside.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100196/viewing-normals-in-blender

Comment: ok, I have checked it, and they are pointing inside.
is there a way to fix it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105125/how-to-flip-normal-direction-in-blender

Comment: Thank you very much! If not you, I would have to remake the entire hand!
Is there a way to upvote your answer or something like this?

Comment: I posted my suggestions as an answer. Please also remember to up vote useful answers to questions I linked so everyone immediately sees best answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like several of your normals are pointing inside.

Answer to this question shows how to see normals in viewport:
[Viewing normals in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100196/viewing-normals-in-blender)

Answer to this question shows how to flip normals of selected faces:
[how to flip normal direction in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105125/how-to-flip-normal-direction-in-blender)

Comment: Thanks! They were indeed pointing inside but now I have flipped them and everything works perfectly!